The ID field verification doesn't pass the validation from the first try
I have the field where user writes the 9-digit number.
The number should have 9 digits and it should pass the Luhn algorithm:
 MaterialTextField(
            label = formModel.someNumber.placeholder,
            text = formModel.someNumber.value,
            onTextChange = {
                formModel.someNumber.value = it
                showError = false
                    if (it.isSomeNumberValid) {
                        showSomeNumberError = false 
                    } else {
                        showSomeNumberError = true 
                    }
                
                validateForm()
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
            errorMessage = if (showError || showSomeNumberError) formModel.errorSomeNumberMessage else null
        )

The Luhn Algorithm check is defined below:
fun String.isSomeNumberValid(): Boolean {
   
    if (this.length != 9) return false


    var sum = 0
    for (i in this.indices) {
        val digit = this[i].toString().toInt()
        val value = if (i % 2 == 0) digit else digit * 2
        sum += if (value > 9) value - 9 else value
    }
    return sum % 10 == 0
}

So, if I type some number that should pass all of those checks, I get an error. When I rewrite one digit from it, the error resets.
I tried resetting the error before it checks for validation, removed the double-check for the number to be 9-digits long, didn't help. I'm quite new to the Kotlin, so any help with explanation will be appreciated.
